# Rails console constantly exits in kubernetes pod

Tags: ruby-on-rails, kubernetes

I run

```
kubectl exec -it pod_name rails c
```

After that Rails console works for a couple of minutes, then it exits automatically. Is there any way to find out the reason, logs or something? Thanks.

Comment: have you deployed any rails application before it? if yes, please provide it's deployment file